# How can you prove $e^{n\ln\left(1-\frac{a}{n}\right)}$ is increasing for $a>0$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How can you prove $e^{n\ln\left(1-\frac{a}{n}\right)}$ is increasing for $a>0$?

The derivative (when showing it as a function of $x$) makes it a lot more complicated.

Comment: You can use induction on $n$.

Comment: Do you mean, for every $a>0$, the sequence with $n$th term $e^{n\ln(1-\frac an)}$ is increasing? Or, for every natural $n$, the function $a\mapsto e^{n\ln(1-\frac an)}$ is increasing on the interval $(0,\infty)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we have $$(e^{n\ln\left(1-\frac{a}{n}\right)})'=\ln\left(1-\frac{a}{n}\right)+n\frac{1}{1-\frac{a}{n}}\cdot \frac{a}{n^2}$$

Comment: we differentiate with respect to $n$ since a is a constant

Comment: why is there 'b' in your derivative ?

Comment: sorry it was just a typo, corrected! it should be a $n$

Comment: it is exponential function, don't you need to multiply the original function ?

Comment: yes i have used the product rule

Comment: I think you need to multiply your derivative by the original function.

Comment: for example, $e^{x^2}$ derivative would be $2x*e^{x^2}$

Answer (score 3):

By hand – no induction required:

As $a>0$, $\;\dfrac an>\dfrac a{n+1}$Now consider the power series expansions:
\begin{align}
n\log\Bigl(1-\dfrac an\Bigr)&=-n\sum_{k\ge1}\dfrac {a^k}{k\,n^k}=-\sum_{k\ge1}\frac {a^k}{k\,n^{k-1}}, \\
(n+1)\log\Bigl(1-\dfrac a{n+1}\Bigr)&=-(n+1)\sum_{k\ge1}\dfrac {a^k}{k\,(n+1)^k}=-\sum_{k\ge1}\frac {a^k}{k\,(n+1)^{k-1}}, 
\end{align}
Now each term of these series satisfies the inequality
$$\frac {a^k}{k\,n^{k-1}}>\frac {a^k}{k\,(n+1)^{k-1}}, \quad \text{whence}\quad\sum_{k\ge1}\frac {a^k}{k\,n^{k-1}}>\sum_{k\ge1}\frac {a^k}{k\,(n+1)^{k-1}},$$
and finally, changing the signs:
$$n\log\Bigl(1-\dfrac an\Bigr)< (n+1)\log\Bigl(1-\dfrac a{n+1}\Bigr)$$

Note the sums of the series satisfy a *strict* inequality becaiuse, for instance, the first terms satisfy one.